# How to disable `npm install`

Tags: npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

We are currently moving everything to `yarn` and I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to disable `npm`'s ability to add/install/update/delete packages? When searching online it seems like everything is talking about doing this in Visual Studio where as I'm looking for something that would disable this across any of our developers machines and ideally `echo` the equivalent `yarn` command.

Is this something that is possible?

Comment: create an alias which does an echo instead?

Comment: I tried adding an npm script named install and it runs post-install. I believe an alias would need to be setup on each machine (correct?). I'm looking for something that would prevent anyone pulling down our repo from accidentally running anything beyond `npm run [script-name]`. If that *needed* to be disabled as well that is fine since `yarn` can do that as well.